# segmentation fault appearing when program parameters are over a certain threshold

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm writing this fairly big network simulator in C++. I've been regularly testing individual pieces as I was developing them, and after putting everything together it seems to work as long as the load I impose on the simulator is not too big (it's a P2P content distribution simulator, so the more different "contents" I introduce the more data transfers the simulator will have to handle). Anything above a certain threshold of the number of different contents being simulated will result in an abrupt SIGSEGV after several minutes of smooth running. I assumed there was a memory leak that was eventually becoming too large and messing things up, but a valgrind run with the parameters below the threshold terminated flawlessly. However, if I try to run the program with valgrind using a critical value for the content number, after a certain point I start to get memory access errors in functions that previously presented no problems:

```
==5987== Invalid read of size 8
==5987==    at 0x40524E: Scheduler::advanceClock() (Scheduler.cpp:38)
==5987==    by 0x45BA73: TestRun::execute() (TestRun.cpp:73)
==5987==    by 0x45522B: main (CDSim.cpp:131)
==5987==  Address 0x2e63bc70 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 32 free'd
==5987==    at 0x4C2A4BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5987==    by 0x405487: Scheduler::advanceClock() (Scheduler.cpp:69)
==5987==    by 0x45BA73: TestRun::execute() (TestRun.cpp:73)
==5987==    by 0x45522B: main (CDSim.cpp:131)
==5987==
==5987== Invalid read of size 4
==5987==    at 0x40584E: Request::getSimTime() const (Event.hpp:45)
==5987==    by 0x40525C: Scheduler::advanceClock() (Scheduler.cpp:38)
==5987==    by 0x45BA73: TestRun::execute() (TestRun.cpp:73)
==5987==    by 0x45522B: main (CDSim.cpp:131)
==5987==  Address 0x2e63bc78 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 32 free'd
==5987==    at 0x4C2A4BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5987==    by 0x405487: Scheduler::advanceClock() (Scheduler.cpp:69)
==5987==    by 0x45BA73: TestRun::execute() (TestRun.cpp:73)
==5987==    by 0x45522B: main (CDSim.cpp:131)
==5987==
```

I know it might be hard to give an answer without seeing the whole code, but is there a "high-level" hint on what might be going on here? I don't understand why a function that seems to work normally suddenly starts misbehaving. Is there something obvious that I'm missing maybe?

The incriminated line in the previous valgrind log is `if (nextEvent->getSimTime() < this->getSimTime())` in the following block:

```
bool Scheduler::advanceClock() {
  if (pendingEvents.size() == 0) {
    std::cerr << "WARNING: Scheduler::advanceClock() - Empty event queue before "
        "reaching the termination event" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
  const Event* nextEvent = pendingEvents.top();
  // Check that the event is not scheduled in the past
  if (nextEvent->getSimTime() < this->getSimTime()) {
    std::cerr << "Scheduler::advanceClock() - Event scheduled in the past!" << 
        std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Simulation time: " << this->getSimTime()
        << ", event time: " << nextEvent->getSimTime()
        << std::endl;
    exit(ERR_EVENT_IN_THE_PAST);
  }
  // Update the clock with the current event time (>= previous time)
  this->setSimTime(nextEvent->getSimTime());
  ...
```

where pendingEvents is a boost::heap::binomial_heap.

Comment: It sounds likely that either `nextEvent` or `this` is an invalid pointer.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: O RLY??? haha just kidding buddy. Sort of.

Comment: @Daniel: I'm not sure it's possible to come to a more helpful conclusion than that with the information given here.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: you're probably right. I was just attempting (and failing) to make a joke.

Comment: Can we see the code a few lines later (line 69), when you delete an event? My guess is that you've left a pointer to a deleted event in the heap.

Comment: Is there some way you can end up deleting the top pending event (in another thread maybe?) after having stored the pointer to it in `nextEvent`, but before actually doing anything with it?

Comment: @MikeSeymour the only reason I'm not showing the rest of the code is that it's fairly big and it involves several jumps to other classes in order to fetch the closest source for the content, assign available bandwidth in a fair way over the network etc. before returning control to the scheduler. Asking anyone to debug through all of that code would be beyond the purpose of a simple question on stack overflow, I'm afraid.

Comment: @sonicwave the code is single-threaded and the only place where I delete events is inside the scheduler, but I do modify the order of the events elsewhere by invoking `pendingEvents.increase()` or `decrease()` on the handle of the event, stored in an ad-hoc map. I did some previous testing on that part but I'm guessing there must be some specific circumstance in which this does not work as intended and I end up deleting the wrong event.

Comment: We don't need all the code; just the code around line 69 where the event is being deleted. That's probably where the problem lies, and you're probably deleting it but leaving a dangling pointer in `pendingEvents`, but without seeing the code there's no way to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what the problem was. When the event was completed and it needed to be removed from the list, my code went something like this:

```
...
// Data transfer completed, remove event from queue
// Notify the oracle, which will update the cache mapping and free resources
// in the topology
oracle->notifyCompletedFlow(nextEvent, this);
// Remove flow from top of the queue
pendingEvents.pop();
handleMap.erase(nextEvent);
delete nextEvent;
return true;
```

The problem was that `oracle->notifyCompletedFlow()` invoked some methods on the scheduler to dynamically update the priority of scheduled events (e.g. to react to a change in the available bandwidth in the network), and thus by the time I removed the top of the queue with `pendingEvents.pop()` in some cases I was popping a different event and leaving the deleted nextEvent in there. By popping the queue before invoking the oracle the problem sorted itself out.

I apologize for having left out pieces of code that might have led to a quicker answer, I'll try to learn from my mistake :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It may be something with `const Event* nextEvent = pendingEvents.top();` Looks like `pendingEvents` is a kind of stack. You may try this:

1. Instrument (means add some tracing as simple as output to the std::cerr | file) the code where you allocate and deallocate the memory (where you use malloc/new, free/delete);
2. As a debugging tool, try to use a smart pointer for Event, which will check the pointer validity during dereferencing (operator ->).